# How to get a list of errors in .nsf application?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, ibm-domino

I have an IBM Domino server with 30 .nsf applications on it.

From time to time these applications get lotusscript errors which can sometimes not be noticed by developers.

For example, if a form uses a method from a library, and the developer changes that method, then when the library is saved, the error will not appear, but a red cross icon will appear next to the form icon in Designer and an entry will appear in the Problems list .

[image: Red cross next to the form icon]

[image: Problems list]

The developer may not notice this cross and this entry, and the problem will only appear to the end user.

I would like to be able to get a list of such errors programmatically, in order to then send the alert to some management system. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the script library that Julian Robichaux posted to recompile scripts. It catches errors, and you can modify the code to suit your needs.

http://www.nsftools.com/tips/LSRecompile.htm

In his test code in the initialization section, you can see how he uses the NotesNoteCollection class and a loop to find specific types of design elements and recompile them. You should be able to use the SelectAllDesignElments method to pick them all up.

As an alternative, if you do some comparative checking of design elements with and without errors using NotesPeek in order to determine what field or flag is set in the design elements with errors, you could skip the recompile and just do the loop through the NoteIDs in the NotesNoteCollection of design elements.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Richard!
The NotesPeek option doesn't work for me because the nsf database doesn't seem to store error information. This information seems to be computed by Designer.
I'll try the compile-from-code option, although that option seems like an overkill to me